# Shutdown / Power off button does always go to suspend on 17.10

Tags: gnome, suspend, shutdown

I've upgraded from 17.04, using Unity, to 17.10, using GNOME. On Unity I was able to assign the shutdown command manually to the shutdown button on my keyboard. With the 17.10 update I moved to GNOME and now I can't change the behaviour of the power button anymore. I tried to simply change the behaviour via dconf, which didn't have any effect. Then I tried to set all button assignments for suspend, hibernation, power off... to "nothing", also via dconf, also without any change. The annoying thing is, if I try to assign a user defined behaviour and press the button the PC goes into suspend immediately.
Is there any other config that need to be changed, to get back my old behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I "solved" this issue, by moving to Kubuntu. KDE allows the user to choose what which button should do. So I simply linked the "switch off" command to the button on my keyboard and now it works as before. No idea why Ubuntu is making such a mess of a simple feature like this.
Additionally I am now able to have buttons on both sides of the window title bars. What a nice feature on a quite large TV screen.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `HandlePowerKey=` line in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. Yours might say `HandlePowerKey=suspend`. **You can change it to say `HandlePowerKey=poweroff`.**

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it a bit and figured out the following:

- the power button of the PC behaves correctly
- the button on my keyboard is always going to suspend, even when I tried to read out the keycode using xev
- using dconf (like I did on 17.04) doesn't show any effect
- if I assign e.g. Ctrl+q to the "Shutdown" command, it takes about half a minute before the system reacts

Now I've decided to revert back to 17.04 and all is working fine. What a crappy update, sorry Ubuntu.